# Why are eno1 and eno2 in this order?

Tags: linux-networking, nic, mac-address, fedora-21

I've just installed a Fedora 21 Workstation system, and it's reversed the order of `eno1` and `eno2` from the CentOS 6 system that was on here before.

```
lspci | grep Eth
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

`00:19.0` has a MAC address ending in `:4f`, while `03:00.0` ends in `:50`.

My understanding was that with a lower PCI address, `:4f` would become `eno1`, but actually it thinks that `:50` is `eno1`.

What's the reason for that, and should I just accept that systems with Fedora 21 will have opposite order from CentOS 6? (We deploy dozens of these systems.)

Comment: It's on the same machine? Did you update its firmware after installing CentOS 6 and before installing Fedora?

Comment: All the same - just booted from the Fedora installer on USB and pressed go. I'm not too bothered about a change, but it seems that the current ordering is perhaps wrong, or my understanding of how they are picked is wrong.

Comment: But... I asked two questions and you only answered one of them!

Comment: Sorry - my "all the same" was just that: I installed CentOS 6 about 2 months ago, and Fedora today, with no firmware updates in between.

Comment: I have no idea why you've got the order reversed, then. Still, as I mentioned below, it's the BIOS that decides what the order is.

Answer (score 3):

For NICs embedded on the motherboard, rather than in PCI/PCI-x/PCIe slots, the "consistent" network device names are actually obtained from information provided by the system BIOS.

[To quote Dell](http://linux.dell.com/files/whitepapers/consistent_network_device_naming_in_linux.pdf), who helped develop this feature:

> The system BIOS indicates the order of Onboard Network Devices to the OS via SMBIOS type 41 records. The system BIOS provides "system slot information" to the OS via type 9 records. The biosdevname makes use of SMBIOS type 41 to suggest names to the onboard network devices and type 9 records to suggest new names for PCI add-in adapters.

In other words, the BIOS decides which onboard NIC is NIC 1 and which is NIC 2.

Thus, I suspect that you had a system BIOS update at some point between your installation of CentOS 6 and your installation of Fedora 21.

Also note that the structure of the names themselves has changed in RHEL/CentOS 7 and Fedora, compared to RHEL/CentOS 6.

[In EL6](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/appe-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming.html), embedded NICs begin with `em` and a number, and NICs on expansion cards start with `p` followed by their bus, slot and function. This was the original biosdevname feature.

[In Fedora and RHEL 7](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Predictable_Network_Interface_Device_Names.html) biosdevname has been replaced with [native systemd support](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/), and the device naming scheme has [changed](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Understanding_the_Predictable_Network_Interface_Device_Names.html). All wired NICs begin with `en`, and onboard NICs continue with `o` and a number, while NICs on expansion cards continue with `p`, the bus number, `s`, the slot number, and optionally `f` and the function number.

(Though, if you upgrade in place from EL6 to EL7, the old-style names will be kept.)

An example of what you'll see from my own systems:

Onboard NICs (in a Dell PowerEdge):

```
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:9f:35:17:f4:32 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9000 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:9f:35:17:f4:34 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

NICs on an expansion card (in a SuperMicro piece of crap):

```
2: enp3s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:45:b8:d2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp3s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:45:b8:d3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```